# What is the best approach for insert and update multiple rows based foreign key using Eloquent?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, slim

I have a table named 'answers' which will store customer answer about questionnaire. The table looks like this

```
answers
+-----------------+
|id (PK)          |
|customer_id (FK) |
|question_id (FK) |
|value            |
|_________________|
```

my request would be like this

```
{
    "customer_id":1,
    "answer": {
        "1":"My Name", //"1" is question_id , "My Name" is value
        "2":"My Phone Number" //"2" is question_id, "My Phone Number" is value
    }
}
```

What i'm trying to achieve is doing a single query or single action on Eloquent instead of foreach the answer one by one to check if the **question_id** and **customer_id** already exists it will update otherwise it will insert the answer to table 'answers'.

By doing foreach/looping one by one per answer data, it shouldn't be a hard problem. However if i already got 3000++ rows in 'answers' table then it would be a big problem.

What is the best approach to do this? 
Maybe is there any third-party library that i can use to do Mass Insert/Updates multiple rows based on foreign key check?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by laravel's `UpdateORCreate` Method which do the exact thing that you want.

In General the statement is like below:

```
$model=Model::UpdateOrCreate(["condtion1"=>"value1",...],["field1"=>"value1",...]);
```

In your case it'll be something like below:

```
$answer=Answer::UpdateOrCreate(["customer_id"=>$customer_id,"question_id"=>$question_id],["value"=>$value]);
```

For more information, Check *[Laravel Eloquent Documentation (Other Creation Methods)](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#other-creation-methods)*